Can I boot from sram when I use arm cortex m3
Normally, we boot from flash or ROM, but what if I want to boot from SRAM area(0x20000000_0x3fffffff) instead of code area (0x00000000_0x1fffffff), should I use startup.s to copy the code to SRAM area?
I've thought about to add some code to startup.s or c files, but I don't know how to start.

What microcontroller are you programming for?  Also, I'm a bit confused as to what you mean by “boot from SRAM.”  If startup.s is what copies your code to SRAM, then surely it must be in flash, so the boot code is actually in flash.

umm, it is like mcu design which use arm cortex m3 core. The ARMCortex-M3 processor boots from Flash memory by default, but in some applications it may be necessary to boot directly from SRAM which i am trying to ask. In my opinion, cpu starts from getting code in 0x00000000 area, and right now i want it get code in sram area

When you power on, you can not have code in SRAM.  There are two use cases, a JTAG debugger loads the code to SRAM or you boot from flash and jump to SRAM.  If you want the later, you can add a fast decompressor to move flash to SRAM and then transfer control there.  Generally, flash is as fast as SRAM on most Cortex-M as the vendors add a read buffer to the flash which keeps the CPU feed with data.  But please be clear on the case you want to handle; there are some similarities, but often the differences result in different overall design...

The JTAG 'debug' mode is often useful for manufacturing and service testing.  Ie, you want to load code that may no be given to end users.  This can be system test/diagnostic code that may not be appropriate in a full device configuration, but fine in a test jig or special circumstances.  But in that case, it should not be much different than the 'development debug' use case.

As far as the cortex-m3 goes, yes absolutely, it does not know flash from ram, and I am sure we can find a number of examples of this (Linux based arm or other processors that contain an mcu also on board) that something else boots the "chip" and then the mcu is loaded from that processor and run.
The typical cortex-m use case though is as the processor in a microcontroller (MCU).  For that use case it is a whole system on a chip, you have your storage and peripherals, processor, whole deal.  So you have to in some way boot the processor from flash.
The STM32s do have a boot from ram mode, but you have to somehow load the code into ram (from the outside, although I think there is a way to do it from flash, depends on the part, a longer story).  So technically you could design a board with some other component (another mcu, fpga, etc) that loads the program into ram and then you can release reset with the right strap pins to have it reset into sram instead of the factory bootloader flash or the application flash.
The raspberry pi pico is a cortex-m that boots from sram, sort of.  The application flash is off chip, I am trying to remember if there is a factory rom that does the initial finding of the flash and copies it based on the documented/specified data format the flash must contain or if the logic reads the first 256 or 512 bytes and then that code is responsible for reading the rest of that flash into ram and you execute from ram.
The grown up arm designs are all about copy from flash to ram then reset the processor into that ram instead of run from flash.  And the logic knows how to do this, and an mcu design could definitely do this.  But part of the mcu market is cost and size and such, having the binary and read only in flash and some ram, compared to a relatively big sram, along with a relatively big flash.  That just costs more.  Sram takes twice as many transistors if not four times as many.  Chip size, power and cost.  What market would want this?
The cortex-m as with other purchased IP is likely not hard wired to boot from address zero.  For various reasons arm doesn't or historically does not do this, for example if you want to have an internal factory bootloader, or boot from flash or ram options.  You could do this with the boot address strapped on the core within the chip or you can do this with if-then-elses on the bus controller and let the arm always boot zero.  You will likely find the typical solution for the various mcu vendors is to let the arm boot from zero but you just mirror the address space to select what you want the arm to see at that address.  So the core likely can boot directly to that address and/or you can definitely mirror that address in a design if this is a feature you want (like the STM32 family).
What you can do and perhaps this is what you want to do is on pretty much any of these cortex-m based products is you can do a copy and jump.  Create your real application to run from ram at 0x20000000 or whatever address that mcu uses, but the code that actually boots from flash simply copies your real binary from flash to ram then branches to ram.  This is pretty trivial to implement a handful to dozen lines of asm plus roll your own tool or do some linker script magic to take a binary copy of your real application and compile/link it into the copy and jump application (my recommendation is to not try to make them one big thing, make them completely separate, your real application is its own linker script, etc, bootstrap is easy because you do not have to init .bss nor .data, that results in a binary image.  Then the copy and jump is its own development, its own program, linker script, etc and you do something simple to link the real application in as a binary blob with a length).
I find the copy and jump method can be good for show folks very elementary toolchain building because you do not have to get into read/only vs read/write you can be operating system application like and link the final binary in place (bootstrap is as simple as set the stack pointer and call the C entry point (main)).  Then later get into the complication of flash vs ram and having to carry .data and notes about .bss in the flash and a bootstrap to get them in place before the C entry point.
End of the day the cortex-m has no clue what sram or flash is, it just has a bus that the chip folks connect to, they buy the flash and sram from some other vendor and glue it up with their glue logic in the chip.  ARM does have some address space rules...for the cortex-ms...about what address space can be executable and what can be ram, peripherals and what is reserved for internal core register addressing.  So long as you live within those rules your chip design can boot from whatever your chip design chooses.  And there are no doubt ram only based cortex-m solutions out there, but they are likely not the main processor for that chip they are helpers, loaded by the main processor.
